# Is QML worth using for Embedded systems which run around 600MHz and no GPU?

Tags: qml, qt-quick

Im planning to build a Embedded system which is almost like an organizer i.e. which handles contacts, games, applications & wifi/2G/3G for internet. I planned to build the UI with QML because of its easy to use and quick application building nature. And to have a linux kernel. 
But after reading these articles:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5820 &
http://en.roolz.org/Blog/Entries/2010/10/29_Qt_QML_on_embedded_devices.html
I am depressed and reconsidering my idea of using QML!
My hardware will be with these configurations : Processor around 600MHz, RAM 128MB and no GPU.

Please give comments on this and suggest me some alternatives for this.
Thanks in Advance.

*inblueswithu*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a QML application for Nokia E63 which has 369MHz processor, 128MB RAM. I don't think it has a GPU. The application is a Stop Watch application. I have animated button click events like jumping (jumping balls). The animations are really smooth even when two button jumps at the same time. A 600MHz processor is expected to handle QML easily.

This is the link for the sis file http://store.ovi.com/content/184985. If you have a Nokia mobile you can test it.

May be you should consider building QML elements by hand instead of doing it from Photoshop or Gimp. For example using Item in the place of Rectangle will be optimal. So you can give it a try. May be by creating a rough sketch with good amount of animations to check whether you processor can handle that. Even if it don't work as expected then consider Qt to build your UI.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! Im not sure if i call 4 or 5 qml files from one to another so that they would form a stack as if they are moving through some menu options/settings - then, will this burden my system!

Comment: No, I don't think so. As I said in my answer, I have used 12 QML components, dynamically created (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html) when a New Lap is recorded. Each component is animated upon creation, a slide in kind of animation. It was rather quick when I was constantly clicking the New Lap button and I experienced no-lag at all. I don't know whether the type of processor(ARM or something) has any effect over QML performance. But it should be okay for your 600MHz processor. And I hope, not sure though, Embedded Linux will perform better than Symbian.

Comment: Any chances QML could run on Cortex M3/M4 chip?

Comment: I am not a processor expert. I have given an answer based on my experience. So I could not answer you. But I guess from what I have read, [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34434/gui-library-for-hmi-cortex-m) and [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/requirements-embedded-linux.html) is if you have any sort of embedded Linux running in your chip, it is possible for you to use Qt.

Comment: The answer was given in 2012.  Can QML work without GPU/OpenGL back then? Even today, it's not trivial to switch to the software renderer.

Comment: I don't know about the software rendering part. I just wanted to give QML a try after trying to work with mShell and PyS60 for my Symbian Phone, and it came out pretty well. I don't know whether it used OpenGL in the backend. I animated a lot of elements simultaneously and they were pretty fluid. I don't have FPS numbers though.

Answer (score 0):

QML applications work fine on low-specs Nokia devices. I have made one for [5800 XPressMusic](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/5800_XpressMusic/) smartphone without any problems.

Comment: What about the OpenGL requirements?